# ui-Grid or ag-Grid or any other, which is the best for angular Application?

Tags: angularjs, grid, ag-grid, ui-grid, angular-grid

Which angular grid provides best performance in MVC API Application and great function for client to use?

Answer (score 2):

[ag-Grid](http://www.ag-grid.com) is the best. I am the founder of ag-Grid, so you may find my answer biased. Hoewver I encourage you to look at the website and make your own mind up. You will see the following advantages over others:

1) Excellent performance.
2) Framework Agnostic, so will work with Angular 1, Angular 2, and if you decide in the future React, Aurelia, Web Components or Plain JavaScript.
3) Lots of features (you will see on website exactly what).